# Recoding a Variable in Python similar to R ifelse

Tags: python, r, dataframe, numpy, recode

I am just new in Python, and I am trying to do an analysis. But before that, I want to recode some of the variables. I am wondering if this R code has an equivalent in Python.

```
df$col1 <- ifelse(df$col1 == "yes", 1, 0)
```

Here `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` and `col1` is one of its columns.

Comment: Python has not an actual command to declare variable and they are created in the first moment you assign a value to it in a similar fashion to `example = "A string of text"`. You can explore the following [guide](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python) and this other [site](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/using-python-r-together.html) if you are interested in approaches to using both R and Python altogether.

Comment: I do not know R, but I am assuming that `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` object and your code essentially wants to convert the values of its `col1` column to 0 and 1. If that's the case, a fast way to do it is `df['col1'] = (df['col1'] == "yes")*1` . If you want, I can convert this to a proper answer in which I will explain what I did

Comment: @ambmil Was this what you wanted and were my assumptions correct? If so, should I convert it to an answer?

Comment: @kyriakosSt, yes... thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible option - probably the most similar to R's `ifelse` in terms of syntax - is to use the [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == "Yes", 1, 0)
```